# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

[This is the picture of the project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RgMF.png)
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

To enable runtime compilation for all environments in an existing project:

1. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package.
2. Update the project's Startup.ConfigureServices method to include a call to AddRazorRuntimeCompilation.

For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();   
// code omitted for brevity    }
```

[Microsoft official program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project)